# Change screen FlatList onPress

Tags: react-native

I have two screen. 
First screen is HomeScreen, second screen is ProfileScreen.
I used FlatList on HomeScreen and i wanna push to navigation to another screen. But when i used that codes, i saw that error message: "Can not read property 'navigate' of undefined"

Code like that

```
class ProfileScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Profile',
    };

    render() {
        const { navigate } = props.navigation;

        return <Text>Hello, I am profile!</Text>;
    }
 }




class HomeScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home',
    };


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],

        };


    }

    getScreen() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor= 'transparent' onPress= {this.getScreen}>
                            <View style= {{width: 300, height: 'auto'}} >
                            <Text> {item.title} </Text>
                                <View style= {{width: 300, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', marginBottom: 30, marginTop: 15}} /> 
                            </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}



const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }
});
```

Comment: try to use this.props.navigation and add this line in the end export default AppNavigator

Comment: i did not understand, could you explain that?

Comment: change const {navigation} = this.props.navigation

Comment: I meet the same question, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You're losing the context of `this` in your implementation. Fix it with function call:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='transparent' onPress={() => this.getScreen()}>
  ...
  </TouchableHighlight>
)}
```

In addition, you can use pattern:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

navigate('Profile');
```

Comment: it may be not the reason, I meet the same issue, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Inside the constructor bind this to your getScreen method.

Simply add following line inside constructor.

this.getScreen = this.getScreen.bind(this);